# Adding tag to a specific text in helper method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, helper

I have this method in my helper and I'm trying to apply a tag like `<strong>` anytime I get the text "The winner is"

```
  def operation_title(operation)
   result = operation_date(operation)
   result << " "
   description = operation.description_ml
   result << "#{description[0..50]}..." if description.size > 53
   result << description unless description.size > 53
  end
```

I try to add around these lines of code in my method:

```
    result = "#{description[<strong>The winner is</strong>]}" if description.include?("The winner is")
    result.html_safe
```

But I can not get the `<strong>` tag out for my text "The Winner is". What am doing wrong? I am really newbie on ruby.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
result.gsub!('The winner is', '<strong>The winner is!</strong>')
result.html_safe
```

[gsub](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-gsub) replaces match by given string.

Comment: Thanks i have fixed like this

    result.gsub!(/The Winner is/, '<strong>The Winner is</strong>') if description.include?("The Winner is")